# How do I create a sticky sidebar?

Tags: post-class

How do I give the three posts here different div classes?
I'm working with twitter bootstrap and I'm trying to give the first post  and the last one

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=Menucard'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="span4 post move pull-left">
        <?php
            //echo post here
            the_content();
        ?>

    </div> <!-- close .post div -->

    <?php
        $counter++;
        if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not really understand your question, but try this (using bootstrap v3):

```
<div class="clearfix">
<?php $a = 0; $classes = array('post-1','post-2','post-3');
 query_posts('category_name=Menucard'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="<?php echo $classes[$a]; ?> col-4 post move pull-left">
        <?php
            //echo post here
            the_content();
        ?>

    </div> <!-- close .post div -->

    <?php
        $a++; endwhile;
        endif;

    ?>
</div>
```